# Determining effective MSSQL DB Role membership

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

I have created windows user groups and added these groups as logins to the MSSQL 2008 R2 instance. These groups have different database roles assigned. Now I want to determine what is the effective role applicable for a user (x) who is part of one of the windows groups.

What is the way?

Answer (score 2):

If you know which Windows Group the user is in, you can use this inside the database you want to check for:

```
select p1.name as role, p2.name as member
from sys.database_role_members m
inner join sys.database_principals p1 on m.role_principal_id = p1.principal_id
inner join sys.database_principals p2 on m.member_principal_id = p2.principal_id
order by 1, 2
```

If you don't, you can do this:

```
-- Impersonate the user
execute as login = '<YourDomain\YourUser>'

-- Check membership
select name as role
from sys.database_principals
where type = 'R' and is_member(name) = 1

-- When ready, revert out of impersonation
revert
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This query is showing me the fixed roles assigned to the particular user. I want to find out the user defined database roles which have been assigned to a particular user.

Comment: It should show you both. Have you changed context to the right database, i.e. using a `use` statement or the database dropdown in SSMS?

Comment: Thanks Mahmud. I figured out the mistake. But now my problem is that unless a particular user is directly added as login to sql server, it doesnt show the role membership. i want to see something like effective permissions.

Comment: That's what the second thing block of sql does. You effectively impersonate the user you want to check the permissions for and then check the permissions.